# Check if MySQL EVENT ran

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL event as follows:

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `PeriodicPartitioning`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS NOW()
DO
    CALL AddPartition(NOW() + INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
```

`AddPartition(DATE)` is a procedure that adds a new partition to the table according to the given date. I've tested that the procedure does run OK when called explicitly. However, when I create the event (no errors) and wait a couple minutes to see if it's actually doing anything, I can't see partitions created, which indicates it hasn't run successfully.

This is the relative bit from mysql error log:

```
Events status:
LLA = Last Locked At  LUA = Last Unlocked At
WOC = Waiting On Condition  DL = Data Locked

Event scheduler status:
State      : INITIALIZED
Thread id  : 0
LLA        : n/a:0
LUA        : n/a:0
WOC        : NO
Workers    : 0
Executed   : 0
Data locked: NO

Event queue status:
Element count   : 1
Data locked     : NO
Attempting lock : NO
LLA             : create_event:217
LUA             : create_event:221
WOC             : NO
Next activation : never
```

I don't understand what the log says. I suspect something is wrong when it says `Next activation: never`? Can someone explain what that means?

**EDIT**

From the first comment, ti turns out that the variable `event_scheduler` was set to OFF and setting it to `ON` had it running like a charm :)

Comment: `event_scheduler` variable is set to ON?

Comment: Thanks! This is actually the answer :) it's working after setting `event_scheduler` to `ON`